# Centering Math Formulas

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I am using LaTeXila in Ubuntu and I want to center my math equation so I have this written:

```
$\[ 2^{10} \]$
```

But when I try to compile into PDF, it outputs the error:

```
Bad math environment delimeter
```

How do I get it to center math text properly? Thanks

Comment: This is not valid latex syntax. You have to omit both dollar-signs to achieve what you want.

Comment: @user1146332 wow thanks, such an easy fix.

Comment: `$<math>$` is for inline mathematical expressions.

Comment: For basics and not only you can see here http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/ ... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$2^{10}$
```

will give you inline math, i.e., a formula in the middle of the text.

```
\[ 2^{10} \]
```

will give you display math, i.e., a formula separated from the text, and centered.