# Setting the length of the arrow

Tags: math-mode, positioning

> How can I extend the length of the arrows here, and I want to have the line in the middle of the page `\begin{center}` does not work 
>   [image]

and why do I have to write RHS of the arrows in text brackets ?

`Ideals in R $\overset{V}{\underset{I}\rightleftarrows}$ \text{algebraic sets in K^n}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. It seems that there are 3 questions here, it would have been better to split them.

Comment: Regarding the first question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/9517

Comment: Regarding the second: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95980/9517 for the simple version, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/9517 for the detailed one

Comment: And regarding the third: you don't need `\text`, but `K^n` is not valid out of math mode.